# invisible recaptcha submitting form before getting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, invisible-recaptcha

I am using the recaptcha gem. Rails 5.2.

I have the following form:

```
= simple_form_for @quote_request_form, url: quote_requests_path, html: {id: "invisible-recaptcha-form"} do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: 'First and Last Name', 
  .form-group.actions.mt-5
    button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block#submit-btn Submit
  = invisible_recaptcha_tags ui: :invisible, callback: 'submitInvisibleRecaptchaForm'
```

I have added the following javascript for the form:

```
javascript:


  document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      grecaptcha.execute();
  });

  var submitInvisibleRecaptchaForm = function () {
    document.getElementById("invisible-recaptcha-form").submit();
  };
```

I check the value from the recaptcha in my controller as follows:

```
  if verify_recaptcha(model: @quote_request_form) && @quote_request_form.save
    redirect_to quote_confirm_path, notice: "Your quotation request is being processed"
  else
    render :new
  end
```

It all works as long as I use the e.preventDefault(); line. If I remove this line I get a failure with the recaptcha and I can see in the parameters that the recaptcha attriburte is sending in blank data.

I don't understand why I need it as none of the documentation specify it. So I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone see how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `e.preventDefault()` statement otherwise the form will be submitted before recaptcha executes the callback.

This happens because [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) with no **type** attribute has `submit` as the default value/ behavior. If you look at [recaptcha documentation](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#programmatically-invoke), the `<button>` tag has the **type** attribute defined as `button`, which has no behavior associated, thus no action happens when you click at it.

Returning to your case, either you keep the `e.preventDefault()` statement or you set the **type** attribute as `button`:

```
.form-group.actions.mt-5
   button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.btn-block#submit-btn type="button" Submit
 = invisible_recaptcha_tags ui: :invisible, callback: 'submitInvisibleRecaptchaForm'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation.  It works now without the e.preventDefault() as I added the type="button" to the button.